# contact form 7 age verification

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, verification

I have a form that I need to allowed submissions only if the user is 13 years old or older to be able to submit the form.

Is there a way to do this with contact form 7?

Thank you for your help

Comment: just make a required checkbox that users will tick if they are 13 or older

Comment: unfortunately since is the law I need them to put the date of their birthday and if the date is 13 or younger they should not be able to submit the form. Looks like the best option is with javascript, unfortunately, I have no idea how to write this code.  I'm not a coder

Comment: Did you try the [Acceptance Checkbox](https://contactform7.com/acceptance-checkbox/) shown on CF7 site?

Comment: I'm using Acceptance Checkbox and age gap, I got everything to work. My age gap was not working because of a plugin Date Picker I disable it and now everything is working

Answer (score 0):

There was a plugin call date picker that was interfering with my form I turn it off and now everything is working I accomplish this by using Acceptance Checkbox and date of birth by adding a max and min date.

Answer (score 0):

In Contact Form 7, add "max:" into your tag, for example "max:13_years_ago"

Full example:
[date* birth-date max:13_years_ago]

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation to your answer, in order for the next user to understand your answer better.

Comment: Hello, hopefully it's more understandable now.